# sort with id from object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

hi i need sort this object by catId :

```
book {
books : {
1: {id: 1, name: "javascript", catId: 2}
2: {id: 2, name: "ayat", catId: 1}
3: {id: 3, name: "olom", catId: 3}
4: {id: 4, name: "css", catId: 2}
5: {id: 5, name: "chap", catId: 1}
}
}
```

output :

```
book {
books : {
2: {id: 2, name: "ayat", catId: 1}
5: {id: 5, name: "chap", catId: 1}
4: {id: 4, name: "css", catId: 2}
1: {id: 1, name: "javascript", catId: 2}
3: {id: 3, name: "olom", catId: 3}
}
}
```

or for example push `{id: 3, name: "olom", catId: 3}` to a empty array :

```
arrBooks [
{id: 2, name: "ayat", catId: 1}
{id: 5, name: "chap", catId: 1}
{id: 4, name: "css", catId: 2}
{id: 1, name: "javascript", catId: 2}
{id: 3, name: "olom", catId: 3}
]
```

Comment: Is `books` an object or array? If it's an object, this is not possible. If it's an array, there are hundreds of duplicates

Comment: What you want as output `object` or `array` ?if `object` than you no you can't and if `array` than yes you can use `sort`

Comment: @Klimenkomud it's not possible since the keys are integers https://stackoverflow.com/a/38218582/3082296

Comment: @CodeManiac i want output array like this : `arrBooks [
{id: 2, name: "ayat", catId: 1}
{id: 5, name: "chap", catId: 1}
{id: 4, name: "css", catId: 2}
{id: 1, name: "javascript", catId: 2}
{id: 3, name: "olom", catId: 3}
]` from top object

Comment: @MohammadAkbari you can get values from `Object.values(book.book)` if (bools.book is an object ) and than use [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: @Klimenkomud no you can't, you can read [this](https://www.stefanjudis.com/today-i-learned/property-order-is-predictable-in-javascript-objects-since-es2015/)

Comment: @adiga book.books is object but i want output value of this object into array like this : `arrBooks [ {id: 2, name: "ayat", catId: 1} {id: 5, name: "chap", catId: 1} {id: 4, name: "css", catId: 2} {id: 1, name: "javascript", catId: 2} {id: 3, name: "olom", catId: 3} ]`

Comment: @CodeManiac yes Exactly i want this Thankful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) and [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) like this:

```js
const book = {
books : {
   1: {id: 1, name: "javascript", catId: 2},
   2: {id: 2, name: "ayat", catId: 1},
   3: {id: 3, name: "olom", catId: 3},
   4: {id: 4, name: "css", catId: 2},
   5: {id: 5, name: "chap", catId: 1}
 }
}

const sortedBooks = Object.values(book.books)
                          .sort((a, b) => a.catId - b.catId)
                          
console.log(sortedBooks)
```

Comment: How can you start a wiki answer?

Comment: @f-CJ while posting answer you see a checkbox on `bottom right` stating `community wiki` mark that if you want to add answer as wiki, you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki)